# How to avoid the Load in rsync with ssh?

Tags: linux, rsync

I having an large amount of data (300GB) in an Linux server. Now, i want to transfer to another Linux server using the `rsync` over ssh. When i transferring the data it creating huge load in the server. May i know how to avoid the load in the server when transferring huge amount of data over ssh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution to  avoid the  load in the server during the file  between remote and local server by including  ionice  and nice command in rsync

```
ionice - get/set program io scheduling class and priority

nice - run a program with modified scheduling priority

#rsync -r -az --rsync-path="ionice -c 3 nice rsync" -e "ssh -p 8363" username@ip-address:/source-file  /destination
```

Comment: You can also renice an already running process.

Answer (score 7):

Use a weaker ssh cipher, (e.g. arcfour) like this:

`rsync -av source --rsh="ssh -c arcfour" foo@bar:/destination`

There might be even weaker ciphers, but arcfour is my preferred one, since it's not the best trade-off between security and speed (in my case, search for cipher benchmarks, there are many around).
Or don't use ssh at all and run a rsync daemon on the destination server.

Comment: i found it just refer my answer. thanks for your information

Answer (score 3):

Or, if the load you're concerned with is CPU load and you have modern CPU with AES instructions (though it seems unlikely from your description), you can use [Intel Accelerator Engine](http://www.openssl.org/contrib/intel-accel-1.4.tar.gz). There's `README` inside with info on how to set it up. There also may be some distro-related way how to set it up.

To see if you have 'modern' CPU, use `grep aes /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: i found it just refer my answer. thanks for your information

Comment: well your answer is not really mitigating the load, but rather it's impact on other apps, that's why i suggested this solution. though i'm glad you found what work's for you ;-)

Comment: thanks friend, for your information regarding intel accelerator engine . The more load will occur when i execute the rsync .so only i ask how to execute rsync without occurring load

Answer (score 0):

You can supplement it by `Rsync --whole-file`

> Rsync by default on local copies will just copy the whole file, but to
>   reduce network traffic remote syncs are diff'd which greatly increases
>   the CPU load.

```
rsync -av --whole-file -e ssh {source} {destination}
```

[Source](http://andre.ws/blog/posts/reducing-load-caused-by-rsync)